# Python: Global variable in class function

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

```
class LinkedList():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    
    def loopCheck(self):
        global fast
        slow = self.head
        fast = self.head 
        while(fast.next!=None):
            slow = slow.next
            fast = fast.next.next
            if slow.data == fast.data:
                return True
            
        return False
    def lenLoop(self):
        if not(self.loopCheck):
            print("No loop found")
        else:
            print(fast.data)
```

The variable `fast` is not getting recognised in the lenLoop() function. How do I make a variable global inside a class?

Comment: `fast = self.head`, why not using a class attribute, like `self.fast` ?

Comment: why should it be a class attribute? Why can't it be a varibale?

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: If you want data to be saved in an instance it needs to be bound to it. To do that you need to make it `self.fast`. Otherwise `fast` is gone after `loopCheck` executes

Comment: You didn't *call* `loopCheck` in `lenLoop`. Also, `lenLoop` seems misnamed; there's no reason that the value of `fast.data` would correspond in any way to the length of any loop found. You need to compute that in `loopCheck`, and you could simply have `loopCheck` return that value, with any non-zero value indicating a loop and 0 indicating a proper linear list.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it in the constructor of your class as `self.fast` as you have done with `self.head`. Intuitively speaking, self is like a dictionary which stores the values of the variables along with their names so that they can be accessed anywhere within the class.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not calling your function. Try `self.loopCheck()` instead of `self.loopCheck`.

```
def lenLoop(self):
    if not(self.loopCheck()):
        print("No loop found")
    else:
        print(fast.data)
```

Output

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> None
No loop found
```